# Trying to print two heatmaps on the same axis using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I am trying to print two heatmaps side-by-side using subplots with the same y-axis. I am plotting them using seaborn.

Here is my code for the two heatmaps. The data is part of a large dataframe with 45 cols. I am using 4 cols each for the two heatmaps below.

```
sns.heatmap(genre_top10.iloc[:,[13,16,19,22]], annot = True, fmt = '.0f', linewidths=.5)
plt.show()
sns.heatmap(genre_top10.iloc[:,[14,17,20,23]], annot = True, fmt = '.0f', linewidths=.5)
plt.show()
```

But not able to figure out how to print them as subplots with a shared y axis. Please help.

Comment: Create a figure before plotting which has 2 subplots and shared y axis. Then pass the axes as an argument into the seaborn heatmap plotting function

Comment: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)` and then `sns.heatmap(...., ax=axes[0])` and `sns.heatmap(...., ax=axes[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and assign the heatmaps to distinct axes. I'm not sure on the structure of your data, but something like this will adde the heatmaps to distinct axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

genre_top10 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,30))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2)
sns.heatmap(genre_top10.iloc[:,[13,16,19,22]], annot = True, fmt = '.0f', linewidths=.5, ax=ax[0])
sns.heatmap(genre_top10.iloc[:,[14,17,20,23]], annot = True, fmt = '.0f', linewidths=.5, ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much @filiphl. This worked like a charm:)